# How accomplish variable++ in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the equivalent of this script in jQuery (if *a* was an HTML element)?

```
a.value++; and ++a.value;
```

I assume it uses `val()`, but it seems inefficient to use:

```
a.val(a.val()+1);
```

Comment: The question's pretty vague. If `a` is just a normal JavaScript variable, you can use `++` if you like; nothing to do with jQuery. Tatu's answer addresses if you're trying to use the value of some HTML element, but it's total conjecture with the question as it stands now.

Comment: Something else you should probably consider, is whether you want it to apply simply to the first matched element, whether you want a set of elements incremented or whether you want all elements set to the same value. As it stands `a.val(a.val()+1);` will actually set the value of *all* matched elements, to the incremented value of the *first* matched element.

Comment: I am sorry about being vague. I came across this problem when trying to store the value of an HTML input element before incrementing it by one. I have done this before using normal JavaScript however I was trying to access the value using just jQuery. Hence Tatu's answer is just what I wanted, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery is JavaScript, and both `a++` and `++a` work in JavaScript. I assume you are trying to increase the value of an input element by one – unfortunately there's no shortcut to that. You just have to write:

```
a.val(parseInt(a.val()) + 1);
```

Remember to use `parseInt`, otherwise the current value will be interpreted as a string and the 1 will be concatenated instead of added.

`a++` won't obviously work as in your case the `a` is an jQuery object.

Comment: Until now, I never had trouble a++ or ++a misinterpreting something as string. Quick note though: According to jQuery Cookbook, ++a executes faster than a++. The difference is minimal though and can be ignored if you aren't in a massive loop

Comment: `parseInt(..., 10)` to avoid octal problems. `+1` or on its own will cast to `Number`, not necessarily an integer.